# typedef a template with all default arguments

Tags: c++, templates, default, typedef, readability

I declare a templated class with all parameters having default arguments, for example:

```
template<typename TYPE = int>
class Foo {};
```

Then the following two are equivalent:

```
Foo<int> one;
Foo<> two;
```

However, I'm not allowed to just do:

```
Foo three;
```

Is it possible to achieve that with a `typedef` to the same name but without the brackets, like this:

```
typedef Foo<> Foo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the declaration `typedef Foo<> Foo;` is allowed, thereafter the name
`Foo` as a template cannot be specified.
That is, the following becomes invalid.

```
template< template< class > class > struct A {...};
A< Foo > a; // error
```

Though the above `typedef` isn't allowed in practice,
if you still need to write `Foo` as `Foo<>`, a macro like the following
will meet the purpose.

```
#define Foo Foo<>
```

Comment: May be too late but dont use define for this purpose. It will cause problems in many ways. You will NEVER be able to use foo with a different type. You will NEVER be able to use foo in another namespace.

Answer (score 8):

I do something like the following, I don't know if you will like it or not:

```
template<typename TYPE = int>
class basic_Foo {};

typedef basic_Foo<int> Foo;
```

Comment: aka "the stdlib approach". :)

Comment: Yes, the same thing happened with `basic_string` and friends :)

Comment: So you would do that if `basic_Foo<int>` is used a lot more than any other `basic_Foo<TYPE>`? The reason I ask is because it seems like an excessive number of characters to add to a class name, as opposed to: `typedef Foo<int> Foo_int` or something like that.

Comment: @Lex He was trying to replace *entire* definition with its name, I assume he is not planning to use it with another type. In your case, using basic_ would not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't redeclare a symbol with a different type, so whatever you will be able to do won't work as you expect.
If you want to achieve this, use a different name as alias :

```
typedef Foo<> Foo_;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef Foo<> Foo;
```

Gives:

```
prog.cpp:4: error: ‘typedef class Foo<int> Foo’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
prog.cpp:2: error: previous declaration of ‘template<class TYPE> class Foo’
```

The error pretty much tells what the problem is. Compiler sees `Foo` as being re-declared.

However, this shall compile and work:

```
template<typename TYPE = int> class Foo {};

typedef Foo<> FooClone;

int main()
{
   Foo<int> one;
   Foo<> two;
   FooClone three;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Although you can declare a `typedef` for a `class` with the same name as a `class` because you can use a typedef to redefine a name to refer to the type to which it already refers.

```
typedef class A A;
```

or if `A` was already declared as a class:

```
typedef A A;
```

You can't do that with the name of a template (the name of a template isn't a name of a class), you'd have to give it a different name.

```
typedef Foo<> Bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, because `Foo` is already the name for the class template itself, and thus can't be anything else in the same namespace.